# Returning java.util.Map from spark UDF results in scala.MatchError: {} (of class java.util.HashMap)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm new to Apache Spark and I'm learning how to use it in java. I would like to define and use an user defined function (udf) and I get the scala.MatchError by returning a java.util.HashMap.

Here is my code for extracting hashtags from a tweets dataset and adding a new column with a map of the hashtag and it's number of occurrences in the respective tweet:

```
    // Open spark session
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("TwitterAnalyticsExample").getOrCreate();

    // Load training data
    Dataset<Row> twitterData = sparkSession.read().format("json").load(inputFilePath);

        UDF1 extractHashtags = new UDF1<String, Map<String, Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public Map<String, Integer> call(String tweet) throws Exception {
            Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\w*");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tweet);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                result.merge(matcher.group(), 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
            }
            return result;
        }
    };


    sparkSession.sqlContext().udf().register("extractHashtags", extractHashtags, DataTypes.StringType);

    twitterData.limit(50).select(callUDF("extractHashtags", col("text"))).show(20);
```

and following imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Any hint, what am I doing wrong? Is the return type java.util.Map a problem for UDF? What could I use instead?

Comment: yeah had the same problem ((